# Building packages on Travis-CI with proprietary MIP solvers, CPLEX or Gurobi

Tags: github, travis-ci, cplex, gurobi

I have an open-source package on github which uses IBM CPLEX as a dependency. I have also added the ability to use Gurobi Optimizer. These are purchased software projects, which thankfully are available free for academic purposes.

These are MIP solvers, which are for optimization tasks:

http://www.gurobi.com/resources/getting-started/mip-basics

https://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/cplex-optimizer/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurobi

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPLEX

What is the recommended way to build a package with these dependencies? Is this possible?

I don't think I can install the dependencies locally and build them within Travis-CI, especially in an open-source package. There is possibly a similar issue with Docker, but this involves putting your license ID somewhere---this isn't the same with a Travis-CI build though (especially in a configure file in an open-source package). Here's an example: https://github.com/mstrimas/docker-optimizr

What is the way to do this?

Comment: I think the license-file stuff is a tiny problem (although it might need some crypto-approach to combat some potential miss-usage; maybe) compared to what the solver does when generating a hardware-based unique-id and checking this against the license. So just somehow putting a license probably does not work (other hardware id; maybe even changing id's depending on backend) and an install automatic install using VPN is a bit hacky too (and not sure if compatible with terms-of-usage).

Comment: Wouldn't you have this issue with any commercial (licensed) dependency? I wonder if by narrowing this question to CPLEX and Gurobi whether you miss potential answers from those who may have advice in the general case. Which programming language are you using (and which API do you use to connect to these libraries)?

Comment: @rkersh I'm happy to re-write the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem, but I ended up using [mip](https://pypi.org/project/mip/); it's compatible with Travis CI and doesn't need any license.

Cheers